# How can we do tf.tile with extra dimensions in the output?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have a `tensor = tf.constant([1, 2])`, what's the best way of creating a tensor of `[[tensor, tensor], [tensor, tensor]]`, which is `[[[1, 2], [1, 2]], [[1, 2], [1, 2]]]`?

The use case looks similar to `tf.tile`. However, `tf.tile` does not create the extra dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Reshape the tensor before using tile, this example demonstrates:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

tensor = tf.constant([1, 2])
tensor_reshaped = tf.reshape(tensor, (1,1,2))
tf.tile(tensor_reshaped, [2, 2, 1]).eval()

Out[22]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],
       [[1, 2],
        [1, 2]]], dtype=int32)
```